# let every item in ListVIew jump to other Activity

Tags: java, android, listview

I have 16 items in listView layout.How to let every item jump to another activity.I have tried this code ,but nothing happen:(

this is **GroupActivity.java**

```
package com.test.listview;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class GroupActivity extends Activity{
    private ListView listView;
    private ListViewAdapter listViewAdapter;
    private List<Map<String, Object>> listItems;  
    protected SharedPreferences group_sp;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.group);

        listView=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.group1_list);
        listItems=getlistItems();
        listViewAdapter=new ListViewAdapter(this, listItems);
        listView.setAdapter(listViewAdapter);
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,long id) {
                Log.i("mm", " onItemClick ");
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                switch(position){
                case 0:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 7:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 8:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 9:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 10:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 11:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 12:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 13:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 14:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 15:
                    intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), ListViewGroup.class);
                    GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                }

            }

        });
    }

    private List<Map<String, Object>> getlistItems() {
         List<Map<String, Object>> listItems = new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
         for(int i = 1; i<=16; i++) { 
             Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
             map.put("imageButton", R.drawable.goff1);                
             map.put("textView", "Group"+i);          
             map.put("imageView",R.drawable.arrow1);    
             listItems.add(map);   
        }      
         return listItems;   
    }
}
```

this is the code from **Adapter:**

```
package com.test.listview;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private Context context;                         
    private List<Map<String,Object>> listItems;      //group list
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;           //View container
    protected SharedPreferences group_sp;

    /**Custom list control set*/
    public final class ListItemView{
        public ImageButton imageButton;
        public TextView textView;
        public ImageView imageView;
    }

    public ListViewAdapter(Context context,List<Map<String,Object>> listItems){
        this.context=context;
        layoutInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);//创建视图容器设置上下文
        this.listItems=listItems;
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return listItems.get(position);
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    /**list settings*/
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            convertView=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list, null);
            //get space object
            final ImageButton imageButton=(ImageButton)convertView.findViewById(R.id.goff1);    
            imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goff1);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                boolean flag=true;
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if(flag){
                        imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.gon1);
                        flag=false;
                    }else{
                        imageButton.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.goff1);
                        flag=true;
                    }    

                }


            });
            TextView textView=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
            ImageView imageView=(ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.right_image);
//            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
//                
//                @Override
//                public void onClick(View v) {   
//                    Intent intent=new Intent(); 
//                    intent.setClass(context, ListViewGroup.class); 
//                    context.startActivity(intent);
//                }
//            });

            //padding image and word
            imageButton.setBackgroundResource((Integer)listItems.get(position).get("imageButton"));
            textView.setText((String)listItems.get(position).get("textView"));
            imageView.setBackgroundResource((Integer)listItems.get(position).get("imageView"));

        //addListener(convertView);
        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Could anyone help me out this?thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you want to start same activity on `onItemClick` then no need to use `switch case` for starting new activity on every row click just change your code as:

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view
                                                , int position,long id) {
      Log.i("mm", " onItemClick ");
      Intent intent=new Intent(GroupActivity.this,ListViewGroup.class);

      GroupActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
    }

 });
```

Comment: @Xoangle : most welcome friend !!:) after 3-4 days you come back here right?

Comment: no,not the coming back take so long ,the result testing take time.:P

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the activity context instead of the application context..

```
intent.setClass(GroupActivity.this, ListViewGroup.class);
```